# Reading .csv file into 2-dimensional array and using/indexing the values

Tags: java

I have a .csv file with 13 columns and numerous rows containing values of varying types (eg, Strings, ints, doubles), i would like to read in the first 26 rows of this file into a 13x26 array, in a way where i can use the values being read into the array to either display Strings or ints and do math with the ints and then display results. My current code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 
{
    System.out.println("Data from CSV file to be analysed:"+"\n");
    String file = "jrc-covid-19-all-days-of-world_ASSIGNMENT-FIXED.csv";
    List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = null;
    try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)))
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) && i<27)
        {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            i++;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This current code reads in the .csv file but when i try to index the array or use values from the array then i run into problems. So i'm looking for a better way of reading in the file.

Thanks guys

Comment: "i would like to read in the first 26 rows of this file into a 13x25 array" - it should be a 13x26 array, shouldn't it? Otherwise it couldn't hold the last row. "then i run into problems" - you should describe what problems you're running into. Btw, CSV can have escaped strings (depends on how you create them) so you might need to handle that as well. Have a look at the Apache Commons CSV library or similar libraries for an easier way to read CSV data.

Comment: Sorry typo on the 13x25 array part, and by problems i mean, when trying to do math with int values in my array i would try index the value by doing array[i][j]] for whatever position it is and then use this statement in the maths equation, which seems to be wrong, and in general, using array[i][j] didn't work either

Comment: You still need to be more specific. Why does `array[i][j]` cause problems provided that `array` is a 2D array and and the indices are correct? And if the element type is `String`, which your reading would indicate, of course you can't do any math on that. You'd need to parse those values to numbers.

Comment: Ok, ill do some more fiddling around and see if i can get it working

Comment: Could you not make a csv file with 13 rows and 46 columns and just access them according to their index?

Comment: Please give an example of your input and output data. Parsing CSV data can get messy very soon. I would recommend to use a library like jackson-csv,supercsv, apache-csv. This will help you to sort out parsing problems.